# The Table Content Changes Depending on the Dropdown Option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the pricing tables developed via Bootstrap and 1 simple dropdown Javascript.

How can I do so if a user selects "Option 1", then the bullet point that currently says "Gain 100 Emails" changes to "Gain 300 Emails" and "Max Emails per day: 3" changes to "Max Emails per day: 6".

And if a user selects "Option 2", then the bullet point that currently says "Gain 100 Emails" changes to "Gain 600 Emails" and "Max Emails per day: 3" changes to "Max Emails per day: 10".

Unfortunately I'm not a Javascript expert (I'm extremely bad in JS) so I will appreciate for your help.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btn-select").each(function (e) {
        var value = $(this).find("ul li.selected").html();
        if (value != undefined) {
            $(this).find(".btn-select-input").val(value);
            $(this).find(".btn-select-value").html(value);
        }
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '.btn-select', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ul = $(this).find("ul");
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
        if (ul.find("li").is(e.target)) {
            var target = $(e.target);
            target.addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
            var value = target.html();
            $(this).find(".btn-select-input").val(value);
            $(this).find(".btn-select-value").html(value);
        }
        ul.hide();
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    }
    else {
        $('.btn-select').not(this).each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("active").find("ul").hide();
        });
        ul.slideDown(300);
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});

$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target).closest(".btn-select");
    if (!target.length) {
        $(".btn-select").removeClass("active").find("ul").hide();
    }
});
```

```css
/* Custom */


.btn-select {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.btn-select .btn-select-value {
    padding: 6px 12px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 34px;
    text-align: left;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top: none !important;
    border-bottom: none !important;
    border-left: none !important;
}

.btn-select .btn-select-arrow {
    float: right;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    top: 0;
}

.btn-select ul {
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    clear: both;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-top: none !important;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1px;
    right: -1px;
    top: 33px;
    z-index: 999;
}

.btn-select ul li {
    padding: 3px 6px;
    text-align: left;
}

.btn-select ul li:hover {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.btn-select ul li.selected {
    color: white;
}

span.mini {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #31708f;
}
span.more {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #337ab7;
}
.info {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: 5%;
    background: #337ab7 !important;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #fff;
    border: 3px #ddd solid;
}
.info:after {
    content: "\e252";
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    color: #337ab7;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -14px;
    left: 45%;
}
.panel-footer:hover .info {
  display: inline-block;
}




/* icons */

span.glyphicon-preload {
    color: #23b070;
    padding-right: 7px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
span.glyphicon-prio {
    color: #fff;
}

span.glyphicon-more {
    font-size: 11px;
}
.table {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.table>tbody>tr>td {
    padding: 14px;
}
.btn-insta {
    margin-top: 13px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.table-premium p {
    font-weight: 700;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"><!-- table#2-starts -->
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Premium</h3>
        </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="the-price">
                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-select btn-select-light">
                    <input type="hidden" class="btn-select-input" id="" name="" value="" />
                    <span class="btn-select-value">Select an Option</span>
                    <span class='btn-select-arrow glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'></span>
                    <ul>
                    <li>Option 1</li>
                    <li>Option 2</li>
                    <li>Option 3</li>
                    <li>Option 4</li>
                    </ul>
                    </a>
                <span class="mini">Monthly Subscription</small>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-insta btn-success" role="button">Activate</a>    
                </div>
            <table class="table table-premium">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-preload" aria-hidden="true"></span> <p>Gain 100 Emails</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="active">
                <td>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-preload" aria-hidden="true"></span> <p>Emails 0 Back</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-preload" aria-hidden="true"></span> <p>No Survey Required</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="active">
                <td>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-preload" aria-hidden="true"></span> <p>Max Emails per Day: 3</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <span class="more"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> More information!</span>
                    <div class="info well">
                    <span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<br><br>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-prio glyphicon-ok glyphicon-preload" aria-hidden="true"></span> 1 <br>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-prio glyphicon-ok glyphicon-preload" aria-hidden="true"></span> 2 <br>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-prio glyphicon-ok glyphicon-preload" aria-hidden="true"></span> 3 <br></span>
                    </div><!-- well -->
            </div><!-- p-f -->
        </div>
    </div><!-- t#2-ends -->
```

Comment: hey @Morgari could you please tell what will be the changes that needs to be done when a user selects "option3" and "option4"? Is there any set pattern to it??

Comment: Hi @HimanshuVohra, if a user selects "Option 3", then the bullet point that currently says "Gain 100 Emails" changes to "Gain 900 Emails" and "Max Emails per day: 3" changes to "Max Emails per day: 15".

And if a user selects "Option 4", then the bullet point that currently says "Gain 100 Emails" changes to "Gain 1500 Emails" and "Max Emails per day: 3" changes to "Max Emails per day: 20". Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code. I have updated your document on click function. Hope you get what you were looking for:

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target).closest(".btn-select");
    if (!target.length) {
        $(".btn-select").removeClass("active").find("ul").hide();
    }
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass('btn-select-value') && $(e.target).parents('.btn-select-light').length > 0) {
        var gainEmailTxt = "", maxEmailPerDayTxt = "";
        switch ($(e.target).text()) {
            case "Option 1":
                gainEmailTxt = "Gain 300 Emails";
                maxEmailPerDayTxt = "Max Emails per Day: 6";
                break;
            case "Option 2":
                gainEmailTxt = "Gain 600 Emails";
                maxEmailPerDayTxt = "Max Emails per Day: 10";
                break;
            case "Option 3":
                gainEmailTxt = "Gain 900 Emails";
                maxEmailPerDayTxt = "Max Emails per Day: 15";
                break;
            case "Option 4":
                gainEmailTxt = "Gain 1500 Emails";
                maxEmailPerDayTxt = "Max Emails per Day: 20";
                break;
            default:
                gainEmailTxt = "Gain 100 Emails";
                maxEmailPerDayTxt = "Max Emails per Day: 3";
                break;
        }

        $('.table-premium td:eq(0) p').text(gainEmailTxt);
        $('.table-premium td:eq(3) p').text(maxEmailPerDayTxt);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, nothing's working (Including dropdown menu anymore) https://jsfiddle.net/mzdu2v44/

Comment: Hey, you just need to replace document on click function not the entire script.

Comment: Sorry, my bad :D Sure, everything is fine now. Great solution, thanks so much!

Comment: Just one question. I have !two tables on one page. How can I change the content into the second table too? (the content differs) (I'll put it into the fiddle, one moment )

Comment: You can select the second table by its class then modify its content.

Answer (score 1):

This will hopely work (a plain javascript solution):

```
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('tr td p');
function opt1() {
  rows[0].innerHTML = "Gain 300 Emails";
  rows[3].innerHTML = "Max Emails per Day: 6";
}

function opt2() {
  rows[0].innerHTML = "Gain 600 Emails";
  rows[3].innerHTML = "Max Emails per Day: 10";
}

function opt3() {
  rows[0].innerHTML = "Gain 900 Emails";
  rows[3].innerHTML = "Max Emails per Day: 15";
}

function opt4() {
  rows[0].innerHTML = "Gain 1500 Emails";
  rows[3].innerHTML = "Max Emails per Day: 20";
}

var options document.querySelectorAll('.btn-select-arrow ul li');
options[0].onclick = opt1():
options[1].onclick = opt2():
options[2].onclick = opt3():
options[3].onclick = opt4():
```

Comment: Either pu it in a `<script>` tag, or put it in an external js file and refer to it in a script tag. Be sure that the script tag is the last element in the document placed in the `<body>` element. If you are using an external file, say **table.js**, you will put this in your HTML: `<script src="table.js"></script>`